# Laravel 5.1 discrepancy with database migrations table

Tags: database, laravel, migration

I just deployed some new code to our production servers and there is a new db migration task that needs to be run. Unfortunately, Laravel thinks it has run already. When I run

```
php artisan migrate:status
```

this migration shows up as 'Y' even though it doesn't even exist in our migrations table. I have also verified that the changes this migration makes are not in our database. I have run composer dumpautoload but that hasn't refreshed anything. How do I go about fixing this issue without destroying any production data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the specific migration row from your **migrations** table (on the production server), and rerun

```
php artisan migrate
```